# Extract lines containing two patterns

Tags: linux, awk, grep, fasta

I have a file which contains several lines as follows:

```
>header1
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCGGGCCTCTTTTCCTGACGGCCGCCCCCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCCCGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header3
<pattern_1>ATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCC
>header4
GACCGGCACGTACAACCTCCAGGAAATCGTGCCCGGCAGCGTGTGGATGGAGAGGGACGTG
>header5
TGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
```

I want to extract all lines containing both  and  including the header lines.

I have tried using grep, but it only extracts the sequence lines but not the header lines.

```
grep <pattern_1> | grep <pattern_2> input.fasta > output.fasta
```

How to extract lines containing both the patterns and the headers in Linux? The patterns can be present anywhere in the lines. Not limited to start or end of the lines.

Expected output:

```
>header1
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCGGGCCTCTTTTCCTGACGGCCGCCCCCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCCCGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
```

Comment: _I want to extract all lines containing both and including the header lines._ makes no sense to me. Please, add expected output for that input (or be more specific).

Comment: An alternation maybe? `grep -E "pattern|header" file`

Comment: Be aware that fasta files can have multiline sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk), it is an adapted version of awk which is tuned to process fasta files

```
bioawk -c fastx -v seq1="pattern1" -v seq2="pattern2" \
       '($seq ~ seq1) && ($seq ~ seq2) { print ">"$name; print $seq }' file.fasta
```

If you want `seq1` at the beginning and `seq2` at the end, you can change it into:

```
bioawk -c fastx -v seq1="pattern1" -v seq2="pattern2" \
       '($seq ~ "^"seq1) && ($seq ~ seq2"$") { print ">"$name; print $seq }' file.fasta
```

This is really practical for processing fasta files, as often the sequence is spread over multiple lines. The above code handles this very easily as the variable `$seq` contains the full sequence.

If you do not want to install BioAwk, you can use the following method to process your FASTA file. It will allow multi-line sequences and does the following:

- read a single record at a time (this assumes no `>` in the header, except the first character)
- extract the header from the record and store it in `name` (not really needed)
- merge the full sequence in a single string of characters, removing all newlines and spaces. This ensures that searching for `pattern1` or `pattern2` will not fail if the pattern is split over multiple lines.
- if a match is found, print the record.

The following awk does the requested:

```
awk -v seq1="pattern1" -v seq2="pattern2" \
    'BEGIN{RS=">"; ORS=""; FS="\n"}
     { seq="";for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) seq=seq""$i; gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/,"",seq) }
     (seq ~ seq1 && seq ~ seq2){print ">" $0}' file.fasta
```

If the record header contains other `>` characters which are not at the beginning of the line, you have to take a slightly different approach (unless you use GNU awk)

```
awk -v seq1="pattern1" -v seq2="pattern2" \
    '/^>/ && (seq ~ seq1 && seq ~ seq2) {
         print name
         for(i=0;i<n;i++) print aseq[i]
     }
     /^>/ { seq=""; delete aseq; n=0; name=$0; next }
     { aseq[n++] = $0; seq=seq""$0; sub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/,"",seq) }
     END { if (seq ~ seq1 && seq ~ seq2) {
              print name
              for(i=0;i<n;i++) print aseq[i]
            }
     }' file.fasta
```

**note:** we make use of `sub` here in case unexpected characters are introduced in the fasta file (eg. spaces/tabs or `CR` (`\r`))

---

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Comment: Kvantour. Tks to share the Awk book.

Comment: @OXXO be aware that this is a very old book and is just written down as a reference. Better books can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: Tks for the advise . Kvantour

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -A 1 header[12] file
>header1
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCGGGCCTCTTTTCCTGACGGCCGCCCCCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCCCGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
```

`man grep`:

```
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching lines.
          Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
          contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before  matching  lines.
          Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the  -o  or  --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

`grep -B 1 pattern_[12]`could work also, but you have several `pattern_1`s in the sample data so... not this time.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that with awk like this:

```
awk '/^>/{h=$0;next}
     /<pattern_1>/&&/<pattern_2>/{print h;print}' input.fasta > output.fasta
```

And here is a sed solution which yields the desired output as well:

```
sed -n '/^>/{N;/<pattern_1>/{/<pattern_2>/p}}' input.fasta > output.fasta
```

---

If it is likely that multiline records exist, you can use this:

```
awk -v pat1='<pattern_1>' -v pat2='<pattern_2>' '
/^>/ {r=$0;p=0;next}
!p {r=r ORS $0;if(chk()){print r;p=1};next}
p

function chk(   tmp){
    tmp=gensub(/\n/,"","g",r)
    return (tmp~pat1&&tmp~pat2)
}' input.fasta > output.fasta
```

Comment: The multi-record solution is not valid. Multiple lines in the fasta file represent a single sequence just split over multiple lines for easy reading (80 char wide), I belive that in such a case <pattern1> and <pattern2> should be somewhere in the full multiline sequence.

Comment: The solution is still not valid as `pattern1` or `pattern2` can be split over multiple lines.

Comment: @kvantour Ok I gave up on that

Comment: don't, you were very close. I think you should be aware that `pattern1` and `pattern2` is something of the form "CGCATD", and since the sequence can be spanning multiple lines, it is possible that in the file, it is written as "CGC\nATD" or "C\nGCATD" or anything of that sort.

Comment: @kvantour I'm drunk asf rn. But I'll try later

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.medicinehow.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/How-does-x-Works-02-10-1020x560.png) helps ;-)

Comment: @kvantour Updated again. Can't go any further.

Answer (score 1):

If you want grep to print lines around the match, use the -B  flag for lines before, the -A  for lines after, and -C  for both before and after the match.

In your case, grep -B 1 seems like it would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If your input file is exactly as described in your post then you can use:

```
grep -B1 '^<pattern_1>.*<pattern_2>$' input 
>header1
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCGGGCCTCTTTTCCTGACGGCCGCCCCCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCCCGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
```

Where `-B1` will display on top of the matching lines the line before it. The regex used is based on the hypothesis that your 2 patterns are located in the exact order at the beginning and at the end of the line. If this is not the case: use `'.*<pattern_1>.*<pattern_2>.*'`. Last but not least, if the order of the 2 patterns are not always respected then you can use: `'^.*<pattern_1>.*<pattern_2>.*$\|^.*<pattern_2>.*<pattern_1>.*$'`

On the following **input file**:

```
cat input
>header1
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCGGGCCTCTTTTCCTGACGGCCGCCCCCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCCCGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2b
<pattern_2>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_1>
>header3
<pattern_1>ATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCC
>header4
GACCGGCACGTACAACCTCCAGGAAATCGTGCCCGGCAGCGTGTGGATGGAGAGGGACGTG
>header5
TGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
```

**output:**

```
grep -B1 '^.*<pattern_1>.*<pattern_2>.*$\|^.*<pattern_2>.*<pattern_1>.*$' input 
>header1
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCGGGCCTCTTTTCCTGACGGCCGCCCCCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCCCGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2
<pattern_1>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_2>
>header2b
<pattern_2>CGGCGGGCAGATGGCCACCAACAACCAGAGCTCCCTGGCCTGCAATCACTACTCGTGTTTTGCCACCACTGCCCCCACGACCGGCACGTACAAC<pattern_1>
```